# What's the number of bytes does `char` occupied in JAVA

Tags: java, spring, byte

When I use JAVA 8,String is saved with char[],so if i write like follow
String test = "a";
i think `a` is one element in char[],
as we know,char occupied 2byte in JAVA,so i think test.getBytes().length may be 2 but 1

```
String test = "a";
System.out.println(test.getBytes().length);
char c = 'c';
System.out.println(charToByte(c).length);
```

### result is

### 1
2

letter occupied 1byte as we know,but `a` is saved as one element in char[],char occupied 2byte
so i wonder where did i misunderstand

Comment: What's the code of `charToByte`?

Comment: `getBytes().length` prints the size of the array, not the bytes occupied in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The basics on String

`String` holds text as Unicode, and hence can combine Greek, Arabic and Korean in a single String.

The type `char` holds **2** bytes, in the Unicode transfer format UTF-16. Many characters, symbols, Unicode *code points* will fit in 1 `char`, but sometimes a pair of `char`s is needed.

#### The conversion between *text* (`String`) and *binary data* (`byte]}`)

The binary data is always encoded in some `Charset`. And there always is a conversion between them.

```
Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
byte[] b =  s.getBytes(cjarset);
String s = new String(b, charset);
```

##### The number of bytes a String occupies

The string `"ruĝa"` contains 4 *code points*, symbols, glyphs.
It is stored in meory as 4 `char`s of 2 bytes = 8 bytes (plus a small object implementing size).

It can be stored in binary data for some charset:

- in Latin-1 as "ru�a" or "ru?a" (limited feiled conversion)
- in full UTF-32 as 4x4 = 16 bytes
- in Latin-3 as "ruĝa" = 4 bytes
- in UTF-8 as "ruĝa" = 8 bytes

However recently `String` may use instead of a `char` array a `byte` array, with a Charset, so it can save on memory. That relies on the actual content being a single byte encoding. You should not count on this, say for dynamic strings.

#### Answer

```
public static int bytesInMemory(String s) {
    return s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16).length;
}
```

Most code points, symbols, 2 bytes, some 4 bytes each.

And note that `é` might be 2 or 4 bytes: one code point or two code points (basic letter `e` and zero width accent). Vietnamese can even have two accents per letter, so 3 code points.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle docs:

> char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has
> a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or
> 65,535 inclusive).

so long story short, char is a 2-byte encoding as it's using Unicode (but I assume that this might change from 1 implementation of JVM to another)

On the other hand, String can be stored in many encoding including UTF-8 (which is 1 byte), so depending on the JVM and how you created the string